# Is there any background for constraining covariances on fitting GMM?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, covariance-matrix, gaussian-mixture-distribution

On clustering data using GMM model, I often see the option to constrain covariances of each clustered GMM.

For example,

- http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/auto_examples/mixture/plot_gmm_classifier.html
- [Different covariance types for Gaussian Mixture Models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326671/different-covariance-types-for-gaussian-mixture-models)

I can understand that it can improve the performance of classification in a certain situation.
I wonder if there is any mathematical background on these constraints or any papers where this issue is discussed.

Comment: It stops pathological behavior too.  It isn't always about making it better, sometimes it is about making it not stupid.  If you get down to only one sample point for any mixture component it's covariance can try to go to zero, which is pathological.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is mathematical background for the reasoning of structured covariances of GMMS. See, for example, this paper
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/342500.
It discusses structured covariances that can be diagonalized in a certain basis (including circulant, Toeplitz structure) and investigates convergence properties of the underlying EM algorithm.

Comment: Would you be able to briefly summarise the argument(s)? It would make this a more useful answer.