# What do we mean by spherical-shaped clusters and arbitrary shape such as the “S” shape and oval clusters?

Tags: clustering

Partitioning and hierarchical methods are designed to find spherical-shaped clusters.
They have difficulty finding clusters of arbitrary shape such as the “S” shape and oval
clusters.

Comment: One concept is that the clusters are reasonably well described by their second moments.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326671/different-covariance-types-for-gaussian-mixture-models/326678#326678 for illustrations.

Comment: It's not generally true that hierarchical clustering assumes spherical clusters, or has difficulty with clusters of other shapes. It depends on the method. For example, hierarchical agglomerative clustering can detect complex cluster shapes when using single linkage, but not Ward linkage. You might find [this figure](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering) helpful.