# What is the meaning of isotropic gaussian blobs , which are generated by sklearn.datasets.makeblobs?

Tags: normal-distribution, python, multivariate-analysis, dataset, scikit-learn

Could someone explain the meaning of **isotropic gaussian blobs** which are generated by `sklearn.datasets.make_blobs()`. I am not getting its meaning and only found this **Generate isotropic Gaussian blobs for clustering** on sklearn documentation. Also I have gone through this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991961/gaussian-distribution-is-isotropic).

So,heres my doubt

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
# data set generate
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples = 100000, n_features = 2, centers = 2, random_state = 2, cluster_std = 1.5)

# scatter plot of blobs
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c = y, s = 50, cmap = 'RdBu')
```

[image]

```py
# distribution of first feature
sns.histplot(x = X[:, 0], kde = True)
```

**As the the distribution followed by this feature is approximately Normal.**
[image]

```py
# distribuution of second feature
sns.histplot(x = X[ :, 1], kde = True, color = "green", alpha = 0.2 )
```

**The distribution of the second feature is Bimodal which is not normal.**
[image]

```py
# overall distribution of values
sns.histplot(x = X.flatten(), color = "red", kde = True, alpha = .5)
```

**Which is also not normal!**

[image]

```py
# Variance Covrariance Matrix of Features
np.cov(X[:, 0], X[:, 1])
```

Output

```py
array([[ 3.55546911,  4.70526192],
       [ 4.70526192, 19.00023664]])
```

**What does it actually mean by Gaussian here!**. It might be a silly question so appologies in advance.

Comment: Focus on one color: that represents a "blob."  When you use the same scales on the two axes, they are bivariate Gaussian distributions with circular shapes: the latter is what "isotropic" means.  For further distinctions, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/326678/919: maybe that answers your questions?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for explanation and I got it. But someone down voted my answer. What’s wrong in it ?

Comment: I can't tell you, because voting is anonymous.  People frequently downvote posts without warning or comment.  When they do (and there are no other commenters or previous dialog to give you any clues, either), the best interpretation is that the *voter* is confused -- so don't worry about it.

Comment: @whuber. Your words gave a positive feeling to me. I was in doubt what went wrong in my concept. Tysm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `make_blobs()` function draws samples from a special **Gaussian mixture model**.  A general Gaussian mixture model with $k$ clusters has a density of the form
$$
p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^k \pi_i \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \Sigma_i)
$$
where $\pi_i \ge 0$ are the weights of each cluster with $\sum_{i=1}^k \pi_i = 1$, $\mu_i$ are the cluster centers, and $\Sigma_i$ are the cluster covariances.  Here $\mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \Sigma_i)$ refers to the normal Gaussian density with mean $\mu_i$ and covariance $\Sigma_i$.

In particular, for the `make_blobs()` function, each cluster or component has equal probability of being sampled $\pi_i = 1/k$ and the cluster centers can be either specified or in the case of your code randomly generated by setting `centers = 2`.  **Isotropic** refers to the fact that the covariance matrices will all be diagonal
$$
\Sigma_i = \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_i^2 & 0 \\
0 & \sigma_i^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $\sigma_i$ being the standard deviation that is passed in.  By default, all clusters will have the same standard deviation.  A Gaussian mixture model is not Gaussian unless there is only one cluster, which is why your plots don't look Gaussian, but rather a combination of Gaussians.

Comment: you gave the indepth explanation and cleared my doubt. I was in wrong direction and thought that `make_blobs` gives a normal distribution for each features, heres `X1, X2` which is not true. Thanks for explanation. A little suggestion to edit the answer : Please change the subscript of $\pi_k$ to $\pi_i$ in the Gaussian Mixture Model density formula.

Answer (score 2):

**Thanks Talsup, for giving the nice explanation**. I am sharing the things in the nutshell.
[image]

**The code snippet for understanding the** `make_blobs()` **is here.** [make_blobs_notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/Gkchandora/20a786df3017a9e02b5fc48a449fc9ee)

Comment: Could someone explain , why my answer is downvoted? Whats wrong in it?

Comment: The link for the jupyter notebook is broken!